# Setting playback rate for media element in markup

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio, mediaelement

Suppose I have a video element...

```
<video src="media.webm" />
```

Is it possible to set its playback rate in the markup?  If so, what's the proper attribute name?  Neither `playbackRate` nor `defaultPlaybackRate` seem to have any effect.  Of course I can set these with JavaScript just fine, but I'm curious if there's some attribute I can set instead.

Comment: no attribute, JS only afaik

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Ok, thanks, I figured as much.  Could you please post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sadly no, the playback speed can only be controlled by Javascript (as you discovered) using `playbackRate`:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.playbackRate = 0.5;
```

it seems like an omission, but the [markup spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/embedded-content-0.html#playing-the-media-resource) doesn't include `playbackRate` as an attribute, just as a property that can be accessed